# Geometry and Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

There are $p \gt 5$ points on the circumference of a circle, and every two of them are joined by a chord. Assume that no three chords are concurrent within the interior of the circle. How can I find the number of line segments obtained by dividing the chords through their points of intersections?

Comment: Hint: try to think about the relationship between the number of intersections and the line segments. And draw some diagrams for initial inspiration.

Comment: Do you know how to get to the number of intersections

Comment: Yeah i do @ Luka .It's ${n\choose 4}$.And i also know the number of chords are ${n\choose 2}$, and that the answer to above question is some how related to these two results.I am just trying to figure out this relation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone is asking what would one do with the the numbers of line segments that *jvdhooft* correctly calculated in his answer. It is used to calculate number of faces chords divide the circle into. To do that we need to observe the polygon and the circle as one graph with $p + {p\choose4}$ vertices and $p + {p \choose 2} + 2{p \choose 4}$ edges (circle segments count). I'll elaborate more about this now. To calculate the number of faces we need to use Eulers graph formula, but it can only be used on graphs with non-intersecting edges. So our vetices need to be the starting $p$ points plus the number of intersections $p\choose4$ and our edges need to be the number of all line segments plus the number of circle segments. To calculate the number of line segments we can think about smaller number of points and lines.[image]
In this picture there are three lines intersecting at two points. So we can see that there are $7 = 3 + 2*2$. In a general case numbers of line segments will be the number of lines plus  two times the number of intersections. Another way to think about this is like *jvdhooft* said. Now we can apply the Eulers formula: $$F = E - V + 2 = {p\choose2} + {p\choose4} +2$$
where $F$ is number of faces $V$ number of vertices and $E$ number of edges of the graph[image] For more information see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8P8uFahAgc&t=417s

Comment: Thank you it really helped.